# How do I determine what triggered a Life Cycle state change in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to check what caused the app life cycle state to change to Inactive, Resumed etc.. without the User leaving the App?

The Life Cycle state changes when I create a payment intent in the App and I need a way to determine whether it was the User leaving the App or something else that triggered it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at **didUpdateWidget** method. This method gets invoked whenever the widget gets rebuilt (via setState).

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html

If you want to determine what caused the lifecycle change, without the user leaving the app, then that's where I would start.

Comment: Thanks Dan. didUpdateWidget won't help in this case. The widget configuration doesn't change for this to trigger. I have a lifecycle widget used as a root widget

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by checking the current App route name in order to determine what triggered the lifecycle change